# Почему не работает вскавка кода через ${ }?

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает код с $ {...}:

```
document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "<input value='${10 + 12}' class='input_field'...
```

Но

```
value='"+ (10+12) +"'... - работает.
```

И как это применять чтобы работало? Или же не стоит применять данную конструкцию в альтернативу конкатеннации с черодованием переменных?

Comment: кавычки обратные надо ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации написано, что данную конструкцию можно вставлять только в **[шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**, которые выделяются **обратными кавычками**

```js
let test = 15;

console.log(`Тут будет номер ${test}`);
```